# Logical mistake with Date function

Tags: javascript, date

Hi so what i want to say at the beginning i know that the syntax for setMonth() is from 0 - 11. So what i want to do is i have a drop down menu. there you can choose between november and december and pick a day in one of those months. if the picked date is while or after 4 sundays before christmas it should light candles based on the numbers of sundays i have witnessed. (advent wreath).

My Problem if i pick november in my drop down menu my date object is still in december and i dont know why. Here is the code:

```
function adventCalculate() {

for(i=1;i<=4;i++) { //Resets the Output field
    document.getElementById("f"+i).style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById("txtf"+i).innerHTML="";
}

var a = document.getElementById("mm");
var month = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
//Gets the value of the drop down field
var b = document.getElementById("dd");
var day = b.options[b.selectedIndex].value;

var advent = new Date();

advent.setMonth(month-1); //advent.setMonth is always 11, even if i put 10 in the parameter manually

advent.setDate(day);

var xmas = new Date();

xmas.setDate(24);
xmas.setMonth(11);
var adventSonntagDate = new Array(4);
var adventSonntagMonth = new Array(4);
var adventSonntagAusgabe = new Array(4);

var december = 24;

//this checks how many advent sundays ive witnessed

for(i=4;i>=1;) {

    xmas.setDate(december);
    var whatDay = xmas.getDay();

    if(whatDay==0) {
        adventSonntagDate[i-1] = xmas.getDate();
        adventSonntagMonth[i-1] = xmas.getMonth();
        adventSonntagAusgabe[i-1] = "The "+i+". Advent was at "+xmas.getDate()+"."+(xmas.getMonth()+1+".");
        i--;
    }
    if(december>0) {
        december--;
    } else {
        xmas.setMonth(10);
        december = 30;
    }

}
var adventDate;
var aktDate;

//This lets the images of the candle appear. i add 30 so that my script can compare
//30.November to 1.December. My script adds 30 to all december days so 30<31.
// But because of the bug with the date function my site cant distinguish between
//November and December
for(k=0;k<adventSonntagDate.length;k++) {

    if(adventSonntagMonth[k]==10) {
        adventDate = adventSonntagDate[k];
    } else if(adventSonntagMonth[k]==11) {
        adventDate = adventSonntagDate[k] + 30;
    }
    console.log("Der eingegeben Monat ist "+advent.getMonth());
    if(advent.getMonth()==10) {
        aktDate = advent.getDate();
    }else if(advent.getMonth()==11) {
        aktDate = advent.getDate() + 30;
    }

    console.log(adventSonntagDate[k]+" = AdventSonntagDate");
    console.log(adventDate+" = adventDate");
    console.log(advent.getDate()+" = Advent.getDate()");
    console.log(aktDate+" = Help2");
    console.log("---");

    if(adventDate<=aktDate) {
        document.getElementById("f"+(k+1)).style.visibility='visible';
        document.getElementById("txtf"+(k+1)).innerHTML=adventSonntagAusgabe[k];
    }

}

var eve = 30 + 24;//Nov + Dec Xmas
var eve2 = eve - aktDate;
if(eve2>-1) {
document.getElementById("txtf5").innerHTML=+eve2+" days left until christmas."
}else {
    document.getElementById("txtf5").innerHTML="Christmas already passed.";
}

}
```

Thanks for your patience with my long code and excuse my grammar mistakes not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this code

```
var advent = new Date();
advent.setMonth(10);
alert(advent.getMonth());
```

and it alerted `11`.

Why?

Because today is the 31st of the month.  Run it again tomorrow and it won't do this.

You create today's date (31st March), and change the month to November. But of course, 31st November does not exist.  When you give invalid values to the JavaScript `Date` object, the date gets 'rolled' forwards.  So after calling `setMonth` your date `advent` actually contains the date 1st December.

I would recommend creating the date in one go, so `advent` never has an invalid intermediate date that gets rolled forward:

```
var advent = new Date(new Date().getYear(), month - 1, day);
```

Comment: Wow...wow...simply thanks, i would have never noticed that. really thank you, you are my hero!

Comment: @Jakob: no worries, glad to be of assistance.